# Why I cant return Boost::Scoped_ptr from function?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, scoped-ptr

So I try to create some wrapper around boost.extension functions for class creation. So I  have created a function:

```
template <class BaseClass, class ConstructorType>
 boost::scoped_ptr<BaseClass> get_class (shared_library & lib, std::string class_name, ConstructorType value ) {
map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> > lib_factories = get_factories<BaseClass, ConstructorType>(lib);
return boost::scoped_ptr<BaseClass> lib_class(lib_factories[class_name].create(value));
}
```

which calls :

```
template <class BaseClass, class ConstructorType>
map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> > get_factories (shared_library & lib) {
    type_map lib_types;
    if (!lib.call(lib_types)) {
        cerr << "Types map not found!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> > lib_factories(lib_types.get());
    if (lib_factories.empty()) {
        cerr << "Producers not found!" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    return lib_factories;
}
```

but last is not so important. What is important - I can not get my function return=(

I try such way :

```
boost::scoped_ptr<PublicProducerPrototype> producer = get_class<PublicProducerPrototype, int>(simple_producer, "simpleProducer", 1);
```

I also have tried :

```
boost::scoped_ptr<PublicProducerPrototype> producer ( get_class<PublicProducerPrototype, int>(simple_producer, "simpleProducer", 1));
```

but compiler talls me `C2248` it can not call some private member of `boost::scoped_ptr<T>`

So how to make my return... returnable // how to recieve it?

Comment: My guess, without knowing more about the error, is that the copy constructor is private (i.e. the class is intended to be noncopyable) and the return requires making a copy.  You're probably not using the right smart pointer for the job.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`boost::scoped_ptr` is noncopyable.  Since you can't copy a `scoped_ptr`, you can't return one either (returning an object by value requires that you are able to make a copy of it, at least in C++03).  If you need to return an object owned by a smart pointer, you need to pick a different type of smart pointer.

If your compiler supports `std::unique_ptr` you should use that instead (Since it looks like you're using Visual C++, Visual C++ 2010 supports `std::unique_ptr`); otherwise, consider using `std::auto_ptr` or `{std,std::tr1,boost}::shared_ptr`, depending on what your exact use case is.

Comment: If you go with `auto_ptr` (which is basically just a broken `unique_ptr`), keep in mind its problems - mainly, that it's not compatible with the STL containers such as `vector` and `map`.  Personally, I would recommend `shared_ptr` (which is [part of boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm))

Comment: You can either use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try boost::interprocess::unique_ptr.